# Create Update Trigger on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I am seeking some help on writing a AQL trigger on Visual Studio 2010. I've followed many examples of triggers I found searching but I can manage to make it work. Perhaps one of you with more experience in this matter can offer me some help.

Here is the scenario:
I have a database named "testDB". This database has 4 tables, the main table is called Product which consist of 4 columns (productId, qualityControl-1-required, qualityControl-2-required, readyToProcess).

If either qualityControl-#-required is yes then the productId is inserted into the respective Qcontrol table.
Tables QControl1 and QControl2 contain 4 fields (id(pK), productId(Fk),qControlFinished, notes).

The 4th table QControlReady also contains 4 fields (id(pK), productId(Fk),qControl1Done, qControl2Done).

What I want to accomplish is once QControl1 and QControl2 are done and the values on QControlReady reflect so I want to update the Product table in the column readyToProcess to "yes".

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Product_Updated 

ON dbo.Product

FOR  UPDATE ON dbo.QControlReady

AS BEGIN

  UPDATE dbo.Product SET dbo.Product.readyToProcess = "Y"

  FROM UPDATED

  WHERE updated.id = dbo.Product.productId 

  AND dbo.QControlReady.qControl1Done == "Yes" 

  AND dbo.QControlReady.qControl2Done == "Yes"

END
```

Comment: What is not working ?The trigger works when you run it into your sql environment?

Comment: I get and Incorrect syntax near keyword 'UPDATE'

Comment: It is not for, but `BEFORE, AFTER`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the keyword `FOR`exists for a trigger declaration. The keyword before the `UPDATE ON dbo.QControlReady` must be BEFORE or AFTER

Try with one of this (choose BEFORE or AFTER):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Product_Updated 


BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE ON dbo.QControlReady

AS BEGIN

  UPDATE dbo.Product SET dbo.Product.readyToProcess = "Y"

  FROM UPDATED

  WHERE updated.id = dbo.Product.productId 

  AND dbo.QControlReady.qControl1Done = "Yes" 

  AND dbo.QControlReady.qControl2Done = "Yes"

END
```

You do not specify on what table you work, before the BEGIN.

Comment: I get 2 syntax errors: **(1)Incorrect syntax near the keywork ON.     (2) Incorrect syntax near '='.**

Comment: try := instead of == . Oups, forgot to remove the `ON dbo.Product`at the start. No need to sepcify, because you said you update your table after the begin. I updated my answer, try this way.

Comment: Thanks to Zaphod for the response following your example and integrating other examples I found I made it work... thanks
<br/><br/>
`ALTER TRIGGER dbo.QControlReady_Updated
ON dbo.QControlReady
AFTER UPDATE 
AS BEGIN
UPDATE product SET product.readyToProcess = 'Y'
FROM dbo.Product product JOIN  inserted ON product.productId = inserted.productId
WHERE (inserted.qControl1Done = 'Y') AND (inserted.qControl2Done = 'Y');
END;`

Comment: Oh, the == were for an equals condition. I tought it was to set values. Its also better to wrote create or repalce trigger, than alter. Don't forget to accept the asnwer.